# Github OAuth firebase refresh token - React typescript

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, react-hooks, oauth-2.0

I'm using **firebase authentication** and **Oauth** to sign in with **GitHub**. I need to write a custom hook for the refresh token.

Here is the code for my Firebase configuration.

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  GithubAuthProvider,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  NextOrObserver,
  User,
} from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  some codes
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GithubAuthProvider();

export const auth = getAuth();
export const signInWithGitHubPopup = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);

export const userSignOut = async () => await signOut(auth);

export const onAuthStateChangedListener = (callback:NextOrObserver<User>) => onAuthStateChanged(auth, callback);
```

To track user authentication, I used React context and Firebase Observer pattern.
Here is the code for user.context.

```
import {createContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode} from "react";
import {onAuthStateChangedListener} from "../utils/firebase/config";
import {User} from 'firebase/auth';

export const UserContext = createContext<User | null>(null);

export const UserProvider = ({children}: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    });
    return unSubscribe;
  }, []);

  return <UserContext.Provider value={currentUser}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

So wherever I need user auth Information like (**access token and refresh token**), I use the below code.

```
const currentUser = useContext(UserContext);
```

Now, I want to write an Axios interceptors and custom hook to refresh the token. The question is how can I do that?
I would appreciate that if you help me.